# Connecting HP EWS To Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, hp

I have a HP LaserJet 500 color MFP 575 running Futuresmart Firmware 4.7 that I am trying to connect to my Windows Domain through Windows Sign-in/Kerberos.

I put in the Domain Name and the Trusted Domain Servers but when I hit test it says "Authentication Failed".

When I check the credentials on the Security logs of the Domain Controller (Windows Server 2008 R2) it shows a had a Event 4624 then a 4625 which means I logged in and logged out.

Yet the printer shows "Authentication Failed."

Does anyone know any network or firewall or even Active Directory settings I need to get this to stat working?